# Problem with registering service in eureka

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have the following eureka server configuration
Pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Angel.SR6</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the configuration of eureka client.
Pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
<artifactId>account-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>account-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
    <skipUTs>${skipTests}</skipUTs>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application.yml for eureka client:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      default:
        zone: http://user:pass@localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    password: pass
security:
  user:
    username: user
    password: pass
```

Eureka server starts normally.
However when I run eureka-client, this is the result of startup process.
On client side:

```
[WARN ] 2021-02-21 21:22:28 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
[WARN ] 2021-02-21 21:22:28 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_ACCOUNT-SERVICE/localhost:account-service - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

On server side:

```
2021-02-21 21:22:28.541  INFO 5208 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Sun Feb 21 21:22:28 CET 2021, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

What could be the issue that eureka client register process is not authorized with result 401, nevertheless I deliver proper credentials?

Comment: Angel is long not supported. Hoxton is the last supported release that supports boot 2.2.x

Comment: @spencergibb I applied Hoxton.SR10 for eureka server and the same result.

Comment: Can you hit /eureka/apps on eureka server?

Answer (score 0):

For Eureka to work, you need to put some configurations in place.
on your eureka server service you need to enable the Eureka server using the @EnableEurekaServer annotation, like bellow:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class NamingServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NamingServerApplication.class, args);
    }
```

On your client you need to configure the application name in your application.properties something like:

```
spring.application.name=my-application
```

That should work! Don't forget to change your spring cloud version as well!

Comment: I previously applied these solutions. What kind of spring cloud version should I apply ?

Comment: you could try to add `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka`, spring cloud depends from the version of spring boot you are using, check [link](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) on 
Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility